# Can't install xaringan in ubuntu 20.04 within Github Actions

Tags: r, xaringan

I'm trying to use Github Actions to build a Xaringan presentation.
But it seems that it can't find xaringan.
Other dependencies are installed correctly, even xaringanthemer  (see logs link below) !

I tried to see if there is some missing dependencies but even after fiwing that, xaringan is still missing.

## Infos

- Env: Github Actions
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- R: 4.1.0
- `REPO_NAME: "https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/all/__linux__/focal/latest"`

Config file: https://github.com/gflowiz/article_foss4g2021/blob/presentation_FOSS4G2021/.github/workflows/render-xaringan.yaml

## How to reproduce:

clone [repo](https://github.com/gflowiz/article_foss4g2021) and trigger build

## Ideas of possible fix

### Signal to Rstudio and wait for a fix ?

That's strange because Xaringan seems to be present on the repo: https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/client/#/repos/1/packages/xaringan

### Change repo

Can I change to CRAN instead of packagemanager.rstudio.com ? What's the URL  to use ?

Other packages seems to be downloaded from https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib

Answer (score 2):

Your issue came from the spelling: you are using `xarigan` instead of `xaringan` in [your workflow file at line 48](https://github.com/gflowiz/article_foss4g2021/blob/cb42ade97a8895f0f14310dd5dfaf3b05bac0179/.github/workflows/render-xaringan.yaml#L48)

[image]

Therefore, when you try installing the package, you got:

[image]

In your last [workflow run](https://github.com/gflowiz/article_foss4g2021/runs/3351717429?check_suite_focus=true).

---

Here is [a workflow run using the correct syntax](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/article_foss4g2021/runs/3352979621?check_suite_focus=true)
, but it seems to return another error related to a `.gitignore` file missing after generating the `FOSS4G2021_presentation.html` output file:

[image]

I'll let you handle it from here (as I've never used these tools before) :D

Comment: Oh my...The nasty typo... Thanks for your time on that question. I have an idea for .gitignore.